# How to translate plurals in language with multiple cases (most of European)

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Function [format_plural](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_plural/7.x) is useable only if language has only one plural case (English), but I need to use it for Czech language what has (like most languages from slovenian and roman family) more cases for plural.

For example English has two cases:

- 1: bed
- 2-∞: beds

But in Czech we needs more cases for the same word:

- 1: postel
- 2-4: postele
- 5-∞: postelí

<s>And the schema is usually different for different words.</s> (Mistake, it is the same for all words in one language, but different between languages.)

Is there some API in core or in some module that can translate this (for Americans crazy :-)) cases?

Comment: It does seem to be supported if you read through the comments on [`format_plural`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_plural/7.x) and [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/348125). I haven't tried it but it looks like you might use something like `format_plural('1 bed', '@count beds', $count)` and then add translations like `'1 bed' => '1 postel', '@count[1] beds' => '@count[1] postele', '@count[2] beds' => '@count[2] postelí`. Or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

format_plural() does support multiple plural versions in general.

format_plural() only has arguments for singular and plural because english only has those two and the input is always english, Drupal does not support translating interface text from another language than english.

However, it is something that defined per language and not per word, that doesn't work. I'm not aware of a workaround that can handle per-word differences.

Actually, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_declension#Plural_forms, those rules (1, 2-4, 5+) are always the same? So that should just work.

This is how it looks in the UI

[image: Translate example]

Comment: Aha, really all the different rules are always the same limits (1, 2-4, 5+). You just learned me something new about my language. :-) However it does not help us, we still need to deal with two plural forms and still be compatible with languages like English.

Comment: I just added a screenshot how it looks for me when adding Czech as a language and importing translations. As I said, the input for format_plural() is english, but the output will use the correct plural form for the target language

Comment: Btw, this works only for D8? I can not see this options in a translation form in a D7.